# Firebase sms verification alternative

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I am currently working on a mobile app that uses google firebase verification. I just discovered that many potential users have Do Not Disturb (DND) enabled on their phone numbers which google firebase is having hard time bypassing, as firebase does not provide voice verification alternative.

I want to ask if there are alternative APIs that provide for both sms and voice verifications in android and ios